# Can I have projects with Angular 5 and Angular 7 working and developing on the same machine

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have 1 year old project done with Angular 5 and I want to start new one using Angular 7. Is there any problem to do this on the same machine? The steps in the guide here https://update.angular.io/ advice to update angular/cli to new version. After update is angular/cli going to work with the old projects done with Angular5?

```
$ nodejs -v
v8.15.0

npm -v
6.8.0
```

I ask this question because I don't know what are the dependencies between npm, nodejs, angular/cli, angular in the project, and probably typescript

```
$ ng -v
Angular CLI: 1.7.0
Node: 8.15.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.0.3
@angular/cli: 1.7.0
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/material: 5.0.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.1
@angular-devkit/core: 0.4.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.1
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.0
@schematics/angular: 0.3.1
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.1
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could simply create a new folder and from there run:

```
npm install @angular/cli@latest
ng new my-project
```

this will add a new project with the newest angular cli version while your global angular version still remains the same.

To verify the result you can run

```
ng v
```

(short for the angular cli version) in the terminal both locally and in another folder (to check your global version)

Comment: Thank you. I used both answers to understand what is the idea. The first command installs angular/cli in this new directory in node_modules folder. The next command creates folder "my-project" with another node_modules folder inside. This works. Would be nice though , if there was only one node_modules folder if it is possible to prevent deeper hierarchy. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome - thanks for sharing the result. Now that you created your new angular project you can move this folder around wherever you want (although copying your node_modules will take a while). After you moved the project folder you can also delete the first folder. Or use it further on to create new projects with this CLI version.

Answer (score 2):

you can install Angular locally (without the -g flag), this will allow you to have different versions running on the same mashine
best,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade the same project from angular 5 to angular 7
at first please rename the node_modules file then change angular cli version to latest like

```
npm install @angular/cli@latest --save (Install latest version ignore -g)
```

Then add the rename node_modules folder to your gitIgnore file.

If you want to run your project again in angular 5 then just change the node_modules file to previously renamed file.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same scenario like you. We migrated our project from angular 5 to angular 7.

->Yes, You can migrate from angular 5 to angular 7 in same machine.

->You can just update your dependencies in **package.json** file from 5 to 7 
     or npm install @angular/cli@latest command.

->Kindly remember that not all the dependencies provided in angular 5 will work in angular 7. You would have to find alternative dependencies for some.

[It is better to have your angular 5 and angular 7 project separately on a same machine]